# Extracting comma separated values from String coming from HTTP post

Tags: java, regex, csv

I would like extract comma separated values which I am getting from HTML post request.

Example:

```
****"file"; filename="TEST.csv"
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel
RECEIVERID,RECEIVERSITE,SENDERID,EMAIL_TO
1000003884,PEPSICO LTD.,1005,ZZZ@company.com
1000003884,PEPSICO LTD.,1010,ABC@company.com
------WebKitFormBoundary5ADzaHQgUvmKoZPI
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="submit"
Submit
------WebKitFormBoundary5ADzaHQgUvmKoZPI--****
```

I want to extract only data starting from **RECEIVERID,RECEIVERSITE.... to ,ABC@company.com** by using regex.

Could you kindly help me with this?

Thanks in advance !!
Tanveer

Answer (score 1):

Use `String.split(delimiter)` which will return you an array containing all `String` delimited by the specified delimiter.

See [the doc about String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) for more informations:

Note that the first and last splitted String will contains text that you don't want so you may want to remove the part which is not formatted as `VALUE,VALUE,VALUE` before using the split method.

---

If you really want to use regex, you can do it this way (once again after removing the extra data):

```
String regex = "[\\n|^|,]*(.*?)[,|$|\\n]";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("RECEIVERID,RECEIVERSITE,SENDERID,EMAIL_TO\n" +
                                  "1000003884,PEPSICO LTD.,1005,ZZZ@company.com\n" +
                                  "1000003884,PEPSICO LTD.,1010,ABC@company.com");

while (matcher.find())
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
```

Comment: What's the meaning for `[\\n|^|,]` regex?

Answer (score 0):

```
^[^,]*?(?=\b\w+,)|(.*,[^\n]*)
```

Try this.Grab the capture.Do not forget to add flags `g` and `s`.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lS5tT3/84

Answer (score 0):

If you use the anchors `^`, `$` in your regex then you need to enable  `(?m)` [Multiline modifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html).

```
String text = "****\"file\"; filename=\"TEST.csv\"\n" + 
        "Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel\n" + 
        "RECEIVERID,RECEIVERSITE,SENDERID,EMAIL_TO\n" + 
        "1000003884,PEPSICO LTD.,1005,ZZZ@company.com\n" + 
        "1000003884,PEPSICO LTD.,1010,ABC@company.com\n" + 
        "------WebKitFormBoundary5ADzaHQgUvmKoZPI\n" + 
        "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"submit\"\n" + 
        "Submit\n" + 
        "------WebKitFormBoundary5ADzaHQgUvmKoZPI--****";
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?m)^[^,\\n]*(?:,[^,]*?)+?$");
final Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
while(m.find()){           
    System.out.println(m.group(0));
}
```

**Output:**

```
RECEIVERID,RECEIVERSITE,SENDERID,EMAIL_TO
1000003884,PEPSICO LTD.,1005,ZZZ@company.com
1000003884,PEPSICO LTD.,1010,ABC@company.com
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/eC2cU2/2)